# MySQL search & replace at the beginning/end of a string

Tags: mysql, search, replace

I'm currently developing a search & replace function for my application and I want it to be able to replace a specified string at the beginning/end of a string.
For example:

```
string = "DadaLalaDada"
```

gets

```
string = "DuduLalaDada"
```

when a search & replace at the **beginning** of the string with

```
search  = "Dada"
replace = "Dudu"
```

is performed.

How can I do this in MySQL? I use *REPLACE* to hit every occurrence in a string, but how to perform this only at the beginning/end?

Comment: Theoretically, you could potentially create a MySQL function that searches the first X characters (X being the length of the searched string) to see if it should be replaced.  Also, the [MySQL LOCATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) command might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to have the relevant values appear multiple times in your query, this seems to work:

```
select tab.val, 
concat(replace(substring(tab.val, 1, char_length('Dada')), 'Dada', 'Dudu'),
    substring(tab.val, char_length('Dada') + 1)) as replace_beginning,
concat(substring(tab.val, 1, char_length(tab.val) - char_length('Dada')),
    replace(substring(tab.val, -char_length('Dada')), 'Dada', 'Dudu')) as replace_end
from ( select "DadaLalaDada" as val union select "BlahDadaBlah" ) as tab
```

Results:

```
+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
| val          | replace_beginning | replace_end  |
+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
| DadaLalaDada | DuduLalaDada      | DadaLalaDudu |
| BlahDadaBlah | BlahDadaBlah      | BlahDadaBlah |
+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This query looks for any rows that begin with "Dada", removes "Dada" from the start of these rows, and then prepends these rows with "Dudu":

```
UPDATE Foo 
SET Bar = CONCAT('Dudu', SUBSTRING(Bar, 5))
WHERE Bar LIKE 'Dada%';
```